# Java Runnable Multi threading Sharing Central Object between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, shared-memory, runnable

I am searching for a simple Java Runnable example where 3 individual threads individually add a item to a hash table available to all threads and display on join of thread's completion.

Simple example:

Hashtable

Thread 1:
Add to Hashtable Key1 Keyvalue1

Thread 2:
Add to Hashtable Key2 Keyvalue2

Thread 3:
Add to Hashtable Key3 Keyvalue3

on join print hashtable

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? I mean it is pretty basic, all you need to watch is the synchronization on the Hashtable.

Comment: I've seen an AtomicInteger example, I've also tried synchronization between threads but I have only seen how to pass information into threads and not in the reverse direction to a central hash table. I'm struggling to find a simple hash table example used in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you want is a single HashTable which is edited by multiple Threads? There shall be 3 Threads and everyone shall put a diffent key and a different value into the Table and after every put the active thread shall print out all keys and values in pairs? Am i right? Because if, this might be something:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class Threadexample {

    // Hashtable and Keylist
    private Hashtable<String, Integer> table;
    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> keys;

    // Konstruktor
    public Threadexample() {
        table = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
        keys = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
    }

    // Adds an Item to the Table and prints the table
    public synchronized void addItem(String key, int value, String threadname) {
        // Adding
        table.put(key, value);
        if (!isAlreadyAdded(key)) {
            keys.add(key);
        }else{
        return;
        }
        System.out.println(threadname + "-> Added! Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        // Showing
        showItems(threadname);
    }

    // Bewares of doublicate keys in the keylist
    private boolean isAlreadyAdded(String key) {
        int size = keys.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (keys.get(i).equals(key)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Prints out all Integer with their keys
    private void showItems(String threadname) {
        Set<String> keys = table.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            System.out.println(threadname + "-> Key: " + key + "   Value: " + table.get(key));
        }
        System.out.print(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    // Mainmethod
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Threadexample tex = new Threadexample();
        final String[] keyarray = new String[] { "Zero", "One", "Two" };

        // starts 3 Threads which are adding and showing the Objects
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            final int value = i;

            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    setName("Thread: " + (value + 1));
                    tex.addItem(keyarray[value], value, getName());
                }
            }.start();

            try {
                // Leave every Thread enough time to work
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is perfect! 
I'm now going to incorporate this within my socket application.

Comment: If you want to make it better, you could remove the arraylist and use the keyset of the table. i just was to lazy because i dont know much about sets and i dont wanted to learn it in a few minutes. so if you can handle sets you should really use the set of the table instead of the arrayList, because if you remove an objekt from the table, you will have to update your arraylist

Comment: This is actually completely what was needed, I'd give you more ratings if I could, thank you.

Comment: I added a few things to make it 100% Threadsafe. Please update your version, i forgot in the last one about something, sorry. Now its correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use semaphore for synchronation. Here is an exemple : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html